# Multiple installed versions of the same package?

Tags: meteor, package

I just tried to remove a package:

```
$ meteor remove raix:push

Changes to your project's package version selections:

raix:eventemitter  removed from your project
raix:eventstate    removed from your project
raix:push          removed from your project

raix:push: removed dependency
```

```
$ meteor show raix:push
Package: raix:push@3.0.1
Maintainers: raix
Git: https://github.com/raix/push.git
Exports: Push

[................ snip ....................]

Recent versions:
  2.6.10  May 4th, 2015
  2.6.11  June 29th, 2015
  2.6.12  August 9th, 2015      installed
  3.0.0   October 1st, 2015     installed
  3.0.1   October 6th, 2015

Older and pre-release versions of raix:push have been hidden. To see all 49 versions, run  
'meteor show --show-all raix:push'.
```

Notice the double `installed` (even after `meteor remove raix:push`). Does this mean that I have two versions of Push installed on top of each other in my application?

When I start the app that uses the package, it crashes (as it should), with:

> ReferenceError: Push is not defined

But why does `meteor show` still report two installed versions?

Comment: Well, you got it wrong but the wording is actually pretty bad. `cached` would be better!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you run [`meteor list`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorlist) you will indeed see the package removed from your project.
Running [`meteor show`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorpublish) allows you to see the versions of the package, and shows **which versions are cached locally on your machine with `installed`**. It is not linked to your project.
It means that if you want to [`meteor add raix:push@=3.0.0`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteoradd) you will not have to download this version, the same applies for `2.6.12`.

Note that due to the strict [semver](http://semver.org/) policies of Meteor, running `meteor add raix:push@3.0.0` (removing the `=`) will ask for the last `3.x` version... Which means you will have to download the `3.0.1`!

Comment: Thanks. So "installed" here means "in cache" and NOT "used for this app". A bit confusing IMHO.